# Routing URI wildcard when using prefix

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have been using a route wildcard for my root path (/) successfully until I decided to move my frontend files behind a prefix (/crm). After that I am getting 404's and have no idea how to solve it. I need the wildcard as a catch all for my Javascript frontend routes (/crm/orders/details/12345) which otherwise result in a 404.

So when I remove *prefix('crm')* everything as set up with the below code works fine. Or when I remove *{any}* plus the matching regex, it works partially, on one level deep routes (*/crm* works, but */crm/orders* does not).

But when I have both the prefix and wildcard */crm* gives me a 404.

How do I need to configure this?

## Works

Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php:

```
Route::namespace('App\Http\Controllers')
  ->group(base_path('routes/crm.php'));
```

routes/crm.php

```
Route::get('/{any}', function ()
{
    return view('crm');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

## Does not work

Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php:

```
Route::prefix('crm')
  ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers')
  ->group(base_path('routes/crm.php'));
```

routes/crm.php

```
Route::get('/{any}', function ()
{
    return view('crm');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Output of *php artisan route:list* is as follows

```
| Domain | Method | URI |Name | Action | Middleware  |
*snap*
| | GET|HEAD | crm/{any} | | Closure | |
*snap*
```

Comment: can you send output of `php artisan route:list` when routes not working

Comment: Yes, I've updated my post. The route is listed there.

Comment: Assuming its a back-end-level 404 error it is a wired behavior. What if you make `{any}` parameter optional like `{any?}`. just a shot in the dark.

Comment: Does not solve it, see my answer to the post below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure `{any}` as an optional parameter. In your particular case, the route will only catch `crm/something` routes (where something can be of one or more segments).

```
Route::prefix('crm')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/{any?}', function () {
        dd("I am here");
    })->where('any', '.*');
});
```

However, if you add the `{any}` as optional, it will also catch `/crm`. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Making *{any}* optional makes */crm* not give a 404 but any deeper routes still give a 404. I suspect the issue lies in the regex.

Comment: No it won't.. Just tried and tested. If this doesn't work for you, the issue might lie elsewhere.

Comment: You can see a screenshot of the request [here](https://imgur.com/a/KJHP4cL)

Comment: You are completely right Mozammil. Mistake was caused by some client side code that did a redirect. Stupid mistake from my end. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries. If this helped, please consider marking it as the answer. See [someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)